# select menu, select record and write on a chage with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a select menu on my website and I want to make it once the selection is made that it will update automaticaly the database and of course to be able to read the select values from the database. I have the ajax script ready to be used in check boxed but I would like to modify it for selec menu. Here is the code for check boxes:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
$('input[name=status]').change(function(){
    if( $('input[name=status]').prop('checked') )
       {selectsatus = '1';}
       else
       {selectsatus = '0';}
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "selectbackend.php",
        data: {"selectsatus": selectsatus,
        "id":id 
       },
        })

        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(jqXHR+"--"+textStatus+"--"+errorThrown);});
});//end change
});//end ready
</script>
```

this is my select menu code:

```
<select>
  <option name="status" value="value1">value1</option>
  <option name="status" value="value2">value2</option>
  <option name="status" value="value3">value3</option>
  <option name="status" value="value4">value4</option>
</select>
```

and finally here is the backend.php

```
<?php
$selectsatus = $_POST['slectstatus'];


$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "No connection" . mysqli_connect_error();}

$query = " UPDATE subscription
           SET status = '$slectstatus'
           WHERE id='$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($cxn, $query) or die ("could not query database 1");
?>
```

what I need is the ajax code modified so it will work with select menu instead of checkboxes, right now it works wiht 2 conditions if 1 or 2 , this time it will work on 4 conditions, where it have to select them fromt he database the actual status and on change to write the change inside the tabase.

this is where it reads the status I have a sql dump on the whole table so I can get it from here for the states of the 1 and 0

```
<?php echo "<input type='checkbox' id='$id' name='status'"; if($row['status'] == 1){print "checked='checked'"; }echo "/>";?>
```

Comment: How is this working? : $checkboxstatus = $_POST['slectstatus']; Perhaps it should be 'selectsatus'?

Comment: yes that was from the old version it was checbox before but since I wanted to be select menu I changed it will fix that error to in the code above